# Make Bootstrap 3 have same breakpoints as Bootstrap 2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, breakpoints

I'm in the process of converting a Bootstrap 2 site to Bootstrap 3. I'm not changing the layout at all and I need the breakpoints to remain the same during this conversion.

Bootstrap 2 breaks down to the stacked mobile view at the iPad portrait viewport, which I believe is 992px. I know you can customize Bootstrap 3's breakpoints here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ but I'm wondering what should I set the 4 LESS breakpoint variables to be for it to break down just like Bootstrap 2 does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Bootstrap 2 vs. Bootstrap 3 @media Comparison

### Large Devices:*Desktops*

Bootstrap 2 >= 1200px

Bootstrap 3 >= 1200px

### Medium devices

Bootstrap 2 >= 768px and <= 979px

Bootstrap 3 >= 992px

### Small Devices:*Tablets*

Bootstrap 2 <= 767px

Bootstrap 3 >= 768px

### Extra Small Devices

Bootstrap 2 <= 480px

Bootstrap 3 < 768px

#### Twitter Bootstrap 2 widths:

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
 
/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }
 
/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }
 
/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Bootstrap 2 @media Documentation is found [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive)
Bootstrap 3 @media Documentation is found [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)

[Great Migration Guide](http://bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide)

Answer (score 2):

You might no be able to get the expected behavior, migrating from [twitter-bootstrap-2](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-2) to [twitter-bootstrap-3](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3) because :

- TB3 is mobile first, not TB2
- TB3 uses 4 differents layouts, and TB2 uses 5

Here are TB2 breakpoints :

- `>=1200px` : Large display
- `>=980px` : Default
- `>=768px` : Tablets
- `<=767px` : Phones to tablets
- `<=480px` : Phones

And TB3 ones :

- `<=767px` : Extra smal devices (Default)
- `>=768px` : Small devices
- `>=992px` : Medium devices
- `>=1200px` : Large devices

If you're lucky, `Phones to tablets` and `Phones` styles are similars. If they're, you just have to set those LESS variables :

- `@screen-xs: 480px` *(default)*
- `@screen-sm: 768px` *(default)*
- `@screen-md: 980px`
- `@screen-lg: 1200px` *(default)*

As both `Phones to tablets` and `Phones` layouts were fluid in TB2, you won't have to change anything to get it working in TB3.

If you're **not** lucky, and `Phones to tablets` and `Phones` styles differents, you'll need to adapt your layout. Your problem is that TB3 merged  `Phones to tablets` and `Phones` layouts, and you can't easily remove a breakpoint.